# How disable return of HTML error page with django rest framework?

Tags: django, rest, exception, django-rest-framework

If I have a error outside the libs of DRF, django send back the HTML of the error instead of the proper error response use by DRF.

For example:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def downloadData(request):
    print request.POST['tables']
```

Return the exception `MultiValueDictKeyError: "'tables'"`. And get back the full HTML. How get only the error a JSON?

P.D:

This is the final code:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def process_exception(request, exception):
    # response = json.dumps({'status': status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
    #                        'message': str(exception)})
    # return HttpResponse(response,
    #                     content_type='application/json; charset=utf-8')
    return Response({
        'error': True,
        'content': unicode(exception)},
        status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
    )


class ExceptionMiddleware(object):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        # response = json.dumps({'status': status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
        #                        'message': str(exception)})
        # return HttpResponse(response,
        #                     content_type='application/json; charset=utf-8')
        print exception
        return process_exception(request, exception)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way of returning json would be to catch the exceptions and return proper response (assuming you're using `JSONParser` as default parser):

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status


@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def downloadData(request):
    try:
        print request.POST['tables']
    except:
        return Response({'error': True, 'content': 'Exception!'}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)

    return Response({'error': False})
```

**UPDATE**

For global wise use-case the correct idea would be to put the json response in [exception middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-exception).

You can find example in [this blog post](http://skyl.org/log/post/skyl/2010/09/django-process_exception-to-log-tracebacks-and-debug/).

In your case you need to return DRF response, so if any exception gets raised it will end up in the `process_exception`:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response


class ExceptionMiddleware(object):

    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        return Response({'error': True, 'content': exception}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

Comment: Yep, but that requiere patch each view. I wonder if exist something that could be used globally

Comment: @mamcx I have updated my answer. Please take a look.

Comment: Nice, @mariodev. DRF should include this, it's bad form for a JSON API to return HTML. Perhaps you should submit it? ;-)

Answer (score 7):

You can replace the default error handlers by specifying a custom handler in your URLConf [as documented here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#error-handling)

Something like this:

```
# In urls.py
handler500 = 'my_app.views.api_500'
```

and:

```
# In my_app.views
def api_500(request):
    response = HttpResponse('{"detail":"An Error Occurred"}', content_type="application/json", status=500)
    return response
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

As you can see in the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling).

All you need to do is configure settings.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
   'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
       'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
       'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
    ),
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'core.views.api_500_handler',
}
```

And pointing to a view that will recieve `(exception, context)`

Like this:

```
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler
...
def api_500_handler(exception, context):
    response = exception_handler(exception, context)
    try:
        detail = response.data['detail']
    except AttributeError:
        detail = exception.message
    response = HttpResponse(
        json.dumps({'detail': detail}),
        content_type="application/json", status=500
    )
    return response
```

My implementation is like this because if a expected rest framework exception is raised, like a '[exceptions.NotFound](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#notfound)', `exception.message` will be empty. Thats why Im first calling to `exception_handler` of rest framework. If is an expected exception, I will get its message.

Comment: the `EXCEPTION_HANDLER` key should be used as a global, catch-all error handler, but you could check exceptions here to see what type they are to return the desired response